# How to properly specify .configure command to use the shared 64 bit library?

Tags: centos7, installation

when trying to install pidgin-screenshot with `sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr` i get this error :

```
checking whether libcurl is usable... no
configure: error: 
To compile this plugin *with* upload support, you must have :
 - libcurl >= 7.19.1 (no) and glib>=2.14.0 (not checked).
```

But i have both  `libcurl >= 7.19.1` and `glib>=2.14.0`  available

```
[msingh@centos pidgin-sendscreenshot-0.8]$ sudo yum list installed libcurl glib2
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.excellmedia.net
 * elrepo: mirrors.coreix.net
 * epel: epel.mirror.angkasa.id
 * extras: centos.excellmedia.net
 * ius: syd.mirror.rackspace.com
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * updates: centos.excellmedia.net
Installed Packages
glib2.i686                                                            2.54.2-2.el7                                                          @base    
glib2.x86_64                                                          2.54.2-2.el7                                                          @anaconda
libcurl.x86_64                                                        7.29.0-46.el7  

[msingh@centos pidgin-sendscreenshot-0.8]$ rpm -ql libcurl | grep /usr/lib64
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4.3.0
[msingh@centos pidgin-sendscreenshot-0.8]$ rpm -ql glib2 | grep /usr/lib64
/usr/lib64/gio
/usr/lib64/gio/modules
/usr/lib64/gio/modules/giomodule.cache
/usr/lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0.5400.2
/usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.5400.2
/usr/lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.5400.2
/usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.5400.2
/usr/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0.5400.2
[msingh@centos pidgin-sendscreenshot-0.8]$
```

I believe it is looking inside `/usr/lib` and not inside `/usr/lib64`. How do i make sure that install command looks in the direcory `/usr/lib64` for the required libraries rather than `/usr/lib`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have not installed the corresponding `devel` packages, which contain the headers and other files necessary to compile software.

You should install these packages, e.g. `libcurl-devel` and `glib2-devel`. You may also find that you need other packages as well.